# year not loading in email

Tags: email, smarty, moodle

I'm running Moodle 2.9.1 and I'm sending an email to the new users of the platform. However, when I try to show the year it doesn't work. My current code reads something like this...

```
$string['newusernewpasswordtext'] = '
(...)
<p >
&copy; {$a->year} xxxx
</p>
';
```

and the email would display

```
© {$a->year} XXXX
```

I would like to dump the variable in the mail so i can figure out what's being processed but i have tried several different smarty ways to no avail. Any suggestions?

thanks!!

Comment: there are two possible reasons: the string doesn't go through smarty or the characters are escaped (i.e. &#123;&#36;a-...) before going through it

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of the `<p>` tags. Just use blank lines instead of `<p>`

Also check if the value is being passed - have a look at `function setnew_password_and_mail()` in `/lib/moodlelib.php`

and add this

```
$a->year    = 'xxxx';
```